# Changing location of the Links folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-shell

I am setting up a small network and i am stuck at rerouting the Links folder on Windows 7.

What i am trying to accomplish is to keep some particular directories stored on a server and all client computers will actually link to those folders, one of which is the Links folder.

I took a look at the registry and found most of the things in :

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

But the Links folder isn't there so im wondering if it's possible to sync that folder over several PCs too **without moving all the user directories to the server**

Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will it be OK if you have to change it from GUI? The Links folder properties inside User folder gives the Location tab in which you can change it.

Edit : I found the registry entry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` on a string key named `{BFB9D5E0-C6A9-404C-B2B2-AE6DB6AF4968}`

Comment: gee i dunno how i missed that, but nice catch! I have in mind a script i will write to do this on all computers, but in the worst case scenario i was gonna do what you proposed to so i appreciate all the help :)